# Example to handle an insert in SQL Server 2016 combining a regular value and json data

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

As a quick example, I am trying to add `orderID` to the record for each row of the json data.

```
declare @orderid as int = 22

declare @jdata as nvarchar(max) = '[{"qty":"5","description":"purple zebras ","clientid":null,"projectid":null,"cost":"179.15"}]'

insert into MB_OrderItems (OrderID)
select @OrderID as OrderID
cross apply 
openjson(@jdata)
with (
    qty int,
    description varchar(100),
    clientID int, 
    projectid int,
    cost decimal(18,2)
    ) as ordersarray
```

Answer (score 0):

This method takes your json string, formats it to a table, adds your order ID as a new field, then puts it back to a json string. In order to get the nulls returned in your json string, you have to explicitly tell sql server to return the nulls.

```
declare @orderid as int = 22
declare @jdata as nvarchar(max) = '[{"qty":"5","description":"purple zebras ","clientid":null,"projectid":null,"cost":"179.15"}]'


;with CTE AS (
select *
FROM OPENJSON(@JDATA) 
WITH (qty int '$.qty',
description varchar(100) '$.description',
clientid INT '$.clientid',
projectID INT '$.projectid',
cost money '$.cost',
orderID INT )
)


SELECT 
qty,
description,
clientid, 
projectid, 
cost, 
@orderid AS Orderid 
FROM cte
FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```